# Assigning value to a parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

```
>>> import sys
>>> def hello(name):
    name='Hello, ',name,' !'
    print name
```

This is my code. How do I assign a value to the parameter 'name'?

Comment: You need to read a Python tutorial `def hello(name): print 'Hello', name`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
input = "whatever"
hello(input)
```

Comment: Lol yeah. I wasnt putting inverted commas while inputting strings.

Comment: i was writing - hello(World) instead of hello('World')

Comment: To concatenate the words, use `+` instead of `,`.

Comment: I was getting a tuple when I used ','

Comment: @user2278992 Reading a tutorial isn't the worst idea.

Comment: Don't name a variable `input`. You overwrite the built-in function.